# fix broken german characters

Tags: delphi, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a translation file for German words but I got it broken like this:

Wنhlen Sie eine Fachgrِكe

is there a tool can fix this in utf-8 mode ?

it is for Delphi windows software

thanks

Comment: Is this a one-time fix to a single file, or something you need to run frequently?

Comment: So your question is what exactly?

Comment: You appear to have read a file encoded in code page 1252 (Western European) as code page 1256 (Arabic).

Comment: If it is of any interest, the correct text reads: "Wählen Sie eine Fachgröße"

Comment: @Dave I need to run frequently

@bobince yes how I can restore it ?

@Uwe Raabe thanks alot but what I can do with the rest :) ?

Comment: I am using Delphi 5 , and I need to do this for German Software, plz advice

Comment: What kind of file are the texts stored in? ASCII, Unicode, ...?

Comment: inside mdb access file , thanks

Comment: Tag `german` removed as part of the [**2012 cleanup**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012).

Answer (score 1):

Use an editor such as Notepad++ and convert the file to a format you can use in your app (ANSI, UTF-8)

Comment: ...assuming that the file can be handled as a text file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this:
http://pinyin.info/tools/converter/chars2uninumbers.html